# Eclipse not copying build path libraries to .war file when deployed

Tags: eclipse, jar, web-deployment

I'm creating a JSF Web Application using Eclipse and suddenly i got a **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException** when i deployed my app on the Tomcat Server. I was confused why this happened because all my build path libraries that i had added worked without any problem.

But then i checked the deployed .war file to see whether all my .jar's were there. And to my surprise it wasn't there. And it was the case for **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException** i received. Then i tried adding other libraries. Non of them were copied to the deploying .war file source. But i could use them in my workspace.

Then i created a new project and copied all the sources from my previous. And then it worked fine. It copied everything to the .war file.

But then i had to use another library and i added it to the build path. Then the same issue was raised. That jar file was not copied to the .war file. And anything i added or if i remove something that already worked and add it again, it stops working because those files will also no be copied to the deploying war.

Is this a an Eclipse bug or is there a Configuration that limits the use of libraries? Any JSF configurations?  Can anyone help me on this?

I'm using Tomcat 8, JSF 2.2 with Primefaces 5.1

Comment: This is **not** jsf related

Comment: @Kukeltje thanks, hope it's not a configuration issue in JSF.

Comment: Jsf is library path / pom agnostic.